# Error when including Qt Headers

Tags: c++, qt

I'm pretty new to Qt and I'm having a bit of trouble building with and linking the QMobility lib. I am not using qt creator for this. Here's a sample test.cpp:

```
#include "Qt/qapplication.h"
#include "Qt/qobject.h"
//#include <QtSystemInfo> //
#include "qsysteminfo.h"

int main()
{}
```

build cmd:

```
gcc -c test.cpp -L/usr/include/qt4/ -lQtCore -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/QtSystemInfo
```

**error:
In file included from test.cpp:4:
/usr/include/QtSystemInfo/qsysteminfo.h:51: fatal error: QObject: No such file or directory**

or if I include line 3, which is commented now, it just get a file not found error.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Mmm... not sure, but don't you have to use the Q preprocessor -- try `qmake`.

Comment: no. I'm able to include Qt/qapplication.h as seen above. The problem begins when i use the qmobility library and include qsysteminfo.h.

Comment: @glutz: "I'm able to include Qt/qapplication.h as seen above." The fact that you are able to do this doesn't mean that it is valid to do this. "qapplication.h" is QT's internal header. You have to include <QApplication> and you have to use `qmake` utility with your project file like Alex said - this will add all include directories and libraries necessary. Do like QT docs say.

Answer (score 2):

You should be including like: `#include <QApplication>`.

If that doesn't work, you probably have a bad installation. Try reinstalling.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you create a QT Project file (something.pro) and compile using

```
qmake && make
```

in your terminal. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to hurt yourself that way :-) You'll have hard time writing a makefile to compile without using qmake, supposing you want to take advantage of the Qt meta object system (you should use the moc tool as well). Anyway, just to be clearer, I rewrote your sample like this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QSystemInfo>

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

but you can keep it as you wrote it. To compile this, I had to use this command line:

```
g++ test.cpp -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/local/Trolltech/QtMobility-x86-1.1.3/include/QtSystemInfo -I/usr/local/Trolltech/QtMobility-x86-1.1.3/include/QtMobility
```

Of course, you'll have to change the paths according to the locations of the headers in your system. Remember that each header includes others, so you'll have to "recursively" provide all the necessary include paths. Of course you will have to link the libraries afterwards.

With a test.pro file it would have been simpler:

```
QT      += core gui
CONFIG  += mobility
MOBILITY    += systeminfo
TEMPLATE    = app
TARGET  = test
SOURCES     += test.cpp
```

and this is correctly configured with all the necessary include paths you'll need and correctly links to libraries. You can also use all the Qt extensions to C++ this way.

```
qmake test.pro && make
```

and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

In a standalone Visual Studio Project I came across the same response. I had

`#include <QtCore>`

and the include path as 
 `c:\Qt\4.8.6\include\QtCore.`

The system files had the error:

`QtCore\qobject.h : No such file or directory.`

I added the 
  `c:\Qt\4.8.6\include` 
 to the include path and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the IDE you are using, you should be able to set up a "Qt project". Then the IDE takes care of the trouble, that you and others here try to solve "by hand". CodeBlocks supports Qt-projects, MS Visual Studio, and I think a lot of other IDE's. I suggest you google "`<yourIDE>` Qt-project getting started". Or consider using another IDE. But you definately have to get familiar with qmake, and .PRO-files at a certain point I'm afraid.